# Is there a way to implement Walktrap or Infomap on Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, detection

I've been running community detection algorithms on Neo4j. As I was reading about different algorithms, I wondered if running Walktrap or Infomap on it was possible. Does anyone know if there is such a possibility? Or do I have to move my dataset, based on a real-world scenario, so there are no "ground truth" communities here, somewhere else?

I've been using the Louvain algorithm, but unfortunately, it is not as good as I originally thought. So I have to use other community detection algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom GDS algorithms using the [Pregel API](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/pregel-api/).

Comment: Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define "not good enough" for us? What are you looking for and did not find in GDS? A more detailed problem statement would help us understand and better answer your question

If you were trying the Louvain agglomerative method, you might try the GDS Leiden algorithm; it more reliably create intermediary communities that may align with a hierarchical tree.

Comment: I did run Louvain on it, but some communities have a degree similar to the square root of the number of edges of the graph which, according to the literature, is a bad sign for modularity-driven algorithms. You can read "Community Detection in Networks: A User Guide" for the details. That sums up my problems with Louvain, that's why I'm searching for other algorithms and I read that walktrap and Infomap do avoid this problem.